# VB.Net: SQL check for existing values

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have this code asking the user to choose a username:

```
Dim name As String = InputBox("Input your Username. 15 Characters or Less in Length.", "Choose a Username", "")
Dim chosenName As String = name.ToUpper
```

This code adds it to my database on phpmyadmin:

```
Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO usernames(username) VALUES('" & chosenName & "')"
saveUsernames(SQLStatement)
```

Any code to search to check if the username is already taken in the database?

Database structure:
table name: `"usernames"`

### columbs: `"id"` and `"username"`

**Please go off of this:**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Dim serverString As String = "Database=sql477993;Data Source=sql4.freemysqlhosting.net;User Id=sql477993;Password=cF5%gB2*"
Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
SQLConnection.ConnectionString = serverString
If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
SQLConnection.Open()
MsgBox("Connected")
Else
SQLConnection.Close()
MsgBox("Closed")
End If
End Sub

Public Sub saveUsernames(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
With cmd
.CommandText = SQLStatement
.CommandType = CommandType.Text
.Connection = SQLConnection
.ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
SQLConnection.Close()
MsgBox("Saved")
SQLConnection.Dispose()
End Sub

Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO usernames(username) VALUES('" & chosenName & "')"
saveUsernames(SQLStatement)
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: you could use a trigger or constraint.

Comment: not worried about it being vulnerable at the moment. its just for me only. what are those and how are they used?

Comment: are you using Sql or MySql?

Comment: MySQL with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use textbox than input box so have it this way>>>
`txtUsername.Text` will be the input.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Dim chosenName as String = txtUsername.Text.toUpper()
Private Sub frmMenu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Connect()
End Sub
```

Add a SAVE button:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegister.Click
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
            con.Open()
            query = "select username from usernames where username = ?"
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("username", chosenName)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.HasRows Then 'username already exists
                MessageBox.Show("Username already exists.", "Invalid Input!", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                With txtUsername
                      .Clear() 'clears the textbox
                      .Focus() 'focused cursor to the textbox
                End With
            Else 'username is available
                query = "INSERT INTO usernames(username) VALUES(@username)"
                params = {"username"}
                values = {"" & chosenName}

                SaveUpdateDelete(query, params, values)
                MessageBox.Show("Username successfully saved!", "SAVED!", _
                           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
           End if
End Sub
```

`con` there is your connection and you can have this in your `module`:

```
Public Sub Connect()
    serverString = "Database=sql477993;Data Source=sql4.freemysqlhosting.net;User Id=sql477993;Password=cF5%gB2*"
    con.ConnectionString = serverString
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub SaveUpdateDelete(ByVal sql As String, ByVal parameters() As String, _
 ByVal Values() As String)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
    End If
    con.Open()
    command = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

    For i = 0 To parameters.Count - 1
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & parameters(i).ToString, Values(i))
    Next
    command.CommandText = sql
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Declare these variables anywhere but it would be best if you declare these in your module as well to be able to reuse these variables in different forms.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public con As New MySqlConnection
Public query As String
Public command As MySqlCommand
Public reader As MySqlDataReader
Public serverString as String
```

Comment: i going to add all my existing code to the question details to show what i already have done and hopefully you can edit your answer to only include what i need.

Comment: @SelectGamer go ahead

Comment: @SelectGamer if ID is auto-generated or not, it wasn't stated...so whatever you decide for the id, just add additional parameter upon saving...and by the way, you can reuse the code in module for update and delete as well.. what will change is your sql statement. instead of INSERT INTO, use UPDATE and pass the parameters to SaveUpdateDelete() function
BEST OF LUCK! :)

Comment: is there any simpler and easier way?

Comment: It's a lot of code and a lot of if i think is unnecessary. Can you please only give me the code of what i need based on what i already have cause your just making it even more confusing for me.

Comment: @SelectGamer that's the safest way and more secure easy way. What way do you want then?

Comment: i used what you gave me to import the database table into a DataGridView and searched for the chosenName value in that. it's working now. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In all examples I ignore the string building from your input.

If you want the check while doing the the insert and silently be okay if it is already there you could just modify you sqlstatement to only insert where it doesn't already exist:

```
INSERT INTO usernames(username) 
SELECT chosenName 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM usernames WHERE username = chosenName)
```

But that's probably not what you want since usually you would want to give feedback.

For feed back you could check the result  of a separate statement and handling the result of the query in you VB code:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM usernames WHERE username = chosenName)
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END userNameExists
```

Drawback here is an extra round trip to the db.

To avoid that you could chose throw an error from the single sql if it was already there:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM usernames WHERE username = chosenName)
   RAISERROR --look up this syntax
INSERT INTO usernames(username) VALUES (chosenName)
```

You could have an ELSE for clarity, but I left it out for brevity of example. It is needed in this case since the error will fire or the code will continue.

[msdn raiserror](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

edit: raiseerror ref is for mssql. You need to check for an equivalent in mssql.

Comment: hmm. very interesting ways of doing this. could you be more in depth for the first and second one.

Comment: if else statement form?

Comment: something like `if username doesn't exist then "add it" else display message end if`

Comment: and what is that? i don't think its vb.net but rather query?

Comment: Not sure how much detail was needed. I'll give little more colour, but for the basic sql syntax that an easy lookup. They are sql you add or replace to what you currently have in the sqlStatement.

Comment: all these codes are errors and most items in it are not defined.